# Why do people use npm init not mean init

Tags: node.js, npm, mean-stack

So I am learning the mean stack (mean.io).

And from the tutorials I saw : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OhPFgqHz68o

they use npm init not mean init from the mean website. Can someone explain why?

Comment: you would have to ask them, as they're the only one that would be able to explain their opinion on the matter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`npm init` is the basic, no-frills initialization of any Node.js project, so it's hardly surprising to see it show up. That's usually the first step before installing any Node dependencies.

The "MEAN" stack is a general concept, just as [LAMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LAMP_(software_bundle)) is, and [MEAN.io](http://mean.io/#!/) is one specific, packaged incarnation of it. Don't confuse all Node.js MEAN applications with being MEAN.io applications.

I might be wrong, but that demo shows how to create a MEAN application, not a MEAN.io one.

Comment: No, I think you're right, that's what I was about to comment too. +1!

Comment: I understand. The video showed me mean.io and i thought mean was app not a concept. Should have done my research a lot better.

Comment: I think the MEAN.io name is just needlessly confusing in this matter.

Answer (score 0):

mean init scaffolds a mean application - shallow cloning the latest version of mean, optionally registering to the [mean network](http://mean.io/network) and optionally creating an initial admin user for you.
npm init creates a new node.js app based on whatever you might have in your package.json.